# Is there a better way to update UI periodically

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-handler

On the screen, I display the status indicator or the printer to display is connected or not. And I'm interested to know what the best way to implement it with the best performance.

I've tried to create `Handler` object and call `postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)` and it works as expected:

Init `Handler` and `Runnable`

```java
private static final int SOME_INTERVAL = 10000;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mPrinterUpdaterRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updatePrinterIndicator(); \\ do some stuff
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, SOME_INTERVAL);
        }
    };

private void updatePrinterIndicator() {
        // check printer status and update some view for instance ImageView
    }
```

After that, I need to start `Handler` when activity launch and remove all callbacks when a user leaves the activity so I write:

```java
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mPrinterUpdaterRunnable , 0);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    super.onPause();
}
```

So, if I understand correctly all code within a `run()` method of `mPrinterUpdaterRunnable` will be executed in the main UI thread.

Is there a better way to do this or I use already the best way to do this? To not execute all code in the main UI thread and only for instance `someView.setImageResource(someID)`

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code in a background thread using at least 3 of this options:

1. Using [RxJava](http://reactivex.io/documentation);
2. Using a custom class like [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceMigrationsSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/migrations/AppExecutors.java);
3. If using Kotlin, then Coroutines;

There are other ways to do this. The RxJava has a greater potencial for the long term if you intend to grow your project a lot. Also, this has a much steeper learning curve.

The second solution is great for small-medium projects and the easiest one along with Coroutines.

After adding the AppExecutors class (2nd solution) you would use it like this:

```
new AppExecutor().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do your stuff
        }
    });
```

Let me know if I could help!